# Need to fetch one-to-many model within a Queryset such that the Queryset has same record repeated, one for each child/nested model

Tags: python, django-queryset, django-1.6

I am working with Django 1.6 and have a problem statement as follows:

1. Suppose there are 2 models, Author and Book, so there is obvious one-to-many relation for the author and book model.
2. Now, I need to display the Author's data such that, there is one row for each Book he has written.
3. As the UI part is in backbone js, its hard for me to iterate/display by modifying things in js.
4. So, would like to have this being done at the backend itself.
   Data to be displayed like:

   ```
   Authors name|Authors Qualification|Authors age|Book|Price
   ```

So, I have a Queryset which has , and within this, if i fetch the Books he has published, it gives me all the books published by him. Instead i want them one by one.

Comment: it is not clear to me what it is you are asking. What do you mean *it gives me all the books published by him. Instead i want them one by one*

Answer (score 2):

Just focus on the `Book`s and use [**`.select_related(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) to fetch the `Author`s as well. For example we can print something like:

```
books = Book.objects.select_related('author').order_by('author__name')
for book in books:
    print(book.author.name, book.author.qualification, book.author.age, book.title, book.price)
```

> I am working with Django 1.6.

[django-1.6](/questions/tagged/django-1.6) is no longer supported since **April 1, 2015**. Please try to upgrade as *soon as possible*.